# Should tags contain the word 'moderator'?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems to me that tags like [moderator-selection](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-selection) can be renamed simply to [selection](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selection) without being ambiguous, and avoiding redundancy.

Similarly, [moderator-teams](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-teams) can become [teams](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teams), [moderator-elections](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-elections) can become [elections](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elections) [moderator-bullying](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-bullying) can become [bullying](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bullying) etc., and in future we should actively avoid having tags with 'moderator' in them.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure that your argument is correct in all cases.

Something like [moderator-bullying](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-bullying) is different to [bullying](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bullying) as the former is done from a position of power and the solution is going to be different to that for bullying by regular users.

Also don't forget that ideally each tag should be able to be applied to a question as the only tag on that question and make sense. So something like [selection](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selection) wouldn't work as there is no indication of what you are selecting. You'd need another tag to define that.

Comment: +1 for the first example, it's a really good one.

Answer (score 8):

The `moderator-*` tags are important to distinguish tags that would have a completely different meaning without the `moderator` portion.

As of this post, there are 5 tags with the `moderator` prefix:

- [moderator-selection](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-selection)
- [moderator-teams](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-teams)
- [moderator-elections](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-elections)
- [moderator-relationship](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-relationship)
- [moderator-access](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-access)

Without the leading prefix, the meaning of each is lost.

- `moderator-selection`, which seems to indicate a question about how one should choose a new moderator becomes `selection`. Selection of what?
- `moderator-teams`, meaning a group of people that share moderator duties, becomes simply `teams`. Is this teams of users or teams in a game?
- `moderator-elections` doesn't seem to lose as much meaning by dropping the prefix, but does become more generic. This is especially true if communities have elections for various positions.
- `moderator-relationship`, which appears to be about how interpersonal relationships between moderators and others are handled becomes just `relationship`. This is very generic. It could be the relationship between your community and another community. The relationship between a user and a business partner they occasionally refer to, or it could be the relationship between two people regardless of whether one is a moderator or not.
- `moderator-access` is a question about what privileges a moderator has. By becoming just `access` it could refer to access to the community, access to a subsection of a community or access control problems.

I don't think all tags should have `moderator` in front of them, but in some cases it is important.